# CallLog архивируется в другое место

Tags: android, java

Данные из CallLog не доступны все, а доступно около 300, поначалу я думал, что можно  сделать еще несколько запросов, узнав, какую дату он мне выдал, но оказалось, что они совсем не доступны.

```
        c = resolver.query(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, null, CallLog.Calls.TYPE + " = " + CallLog.Calls.OUTGOING_TYPE + " and " + CallLog.Calls.DATE+ " > " +
                minDate + " and " + CallLog.Calls.DATE  + " < "+ minDate, null, null);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }

    try {
        while(c.moveToFirst()){
            minDat = c.getLong(2);
            while (c.moveToNext()) {

                int operator = 10;
                if (c.getLong(2) < minDat) {
                    minDat = c.getLong(2);
                }
            }
            c.close();

            c = resolver.query(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, new String[]{CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NAME, CallLog.Calls.NUMBER, CallLog.Calls.DATE, CallLog.Calls.DURATION,
                    CallLog.Calls.CACHED_PHOTO_ID}, CallLog.Calls.TYPE + " = " + CallLog.Calls.OUTGOING_TYPE + " and " + CallLog.Calls.DATE + " > " +
                    minDate + " and " + CallLog.Calls.DATE + " < " + minDat, null, null);

            Log.e("Fragment1  ", minDate + "    " + minDat + "    " + maxDate + "    ");
        }
```

Пробовал и вручную задавать выборку даты меньше, чем он выдает:

```
        c = resolver.query(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, null, CallLog.Calls.TYPE + " = " + CallLog.Calls.OUTGOING_TYPE + " and " +  CallLog.Calls.DATE  + " < "+ 1415201307837L, null, null);
```

Ничего не выдает, хотя у меня в журнале звонков около года выдает только за полтара месяца на другом телефоне, где звонков по 30 в день совершается, и того меньше, только за последние 10 дней, в итоге получается, что они хранятся еще где-то в другом месте, может быть, архивируются куда.

Comment: А не пробовал так?

      c = resolver.query(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, null, CallLog.Calls.TYPE + "=? and " +  CallLog.Calls.DATE  + " < ?", new String[] {2, new Date().getTime()}, null);

Comment: Мне нужны только исходящие, но даже если я убираю все условия выборки, он не выводит все записи, а только около 500 звонков вместе с входящими и исходящими, а вот где остальные, непонятно, @Вarmaley.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если изучить исходники CallLogs, видно, что при запросе к внутреннему SQLite БД Android'а стоит ограничение `limit 500` - то есть возвращать не более 500 записей.

Так что все логи на месте, они там же и хранятся, просто он показывает не более 500 записей.

Чтобы увидеть более старые записи, надо запрашивать с фильтром по дате.

Comment: Ну так ведь я такое и делаю, запрос по дате в вопросе, есть такой запрос, но он ничего не выдает.

Comment: У вас запрос, который требует показать все записи, моложе текущей даты (по сути, все даты). Попробуйте задать запрос на показ старых дат (например, год назад).

Comment: @Barmaley я делал два запроса подряд, сначала первый запрос там сохранял самую дальнюю дату, а во втором запросе я делаю выборку меньше этого числа, но ничего не выдало. Попробуйте вы тоже так сделать, и еще где можно посмотреть исходник и какой именно класс, где указывается лимит 500? Хотелось бы посмотреть, может, что в голову придет.